# Scripting in Immediate Window

Tags: vba

is it possible to code short scripts in Immediate Window in VBA?
When I was using for example R or Python I had always open console in which I could easly check how short code is working (for example check the result of `For` loop if it returns range `[a, b]` or `[a, b)`)
So for example: can I write

```
For i = 0 to 5
   Debug.Print i
Next i
```

and run it without creating new module file/creating extra `Sub`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this in the immediate window:

`For i = 0 to 5: Debug.Print i : Next i` and press enter

It is not possible to have line breaks. But instead use a colon.